# "Value does not fall within the expected range" on C# for adding a bug on HPQC

Tags: c#, null, hp-quality-center

This function is supposed to add a new defect on HPQC. However it gives an "Value does not fall within the expected range" when null is in the .addItem(). Does anyone know what might be the problem?

```
public static void addBug()
{
            String qcUrl = "LINK TO HPQC";
            String qcDomain = "DOMAIN";
            String qcProject = "PROJECT";
            String qcLoginName = "NAME";
            String qcPassword = "PASS";

            TDConnection connection = new TDConnection();
            connection.InitConnectionEx(qcUrl);
            connection.ConnectProjectEx(qcDomain, qcProject, qcLoginName, qcPassword);

            BugFactory bugFactory = connection.BugFactory;
            Bug bug = bugFactory.AddItem(null);

            bug.Status = "New";
            bug.Project = "QCIntegration";
            bug.Summary = "Short description of the bug";
            bug.DetectedBy = "Aaron Evans";
            bug.AssignedTo = "Nobody";
            bug.Priority = "Low";
            bug.Post();
}
```

Comment: Why would you add null to something? That's like opening a closet to put nothing in...

Comment: Something about BugFactory does not like the `null` you are adding. Not knowing how type `Bug` or `BugFactory` work, did you try `Bug bug = new Bug()` then adding it?

Comment: @Jeroen1984 , I dont know what else to add in it. Int, string, or keeping it empty is not working.

Comment: @TYH , I just tried this, and I get a nasty error message.

Comment: Try to pass in System.DBNull.Value and see what happens

Comment: What is the expected parameter type of the method `bugFactory.AddItem(null)`?  You are supplying `null`, which it clearly will not accept, but what does it _want_?  A `String`...use `String.Empty`.  Or what, then...?

Comment: What line throws the error?  Are you _sure_ it's the `AddItem()` line?

Comment: I think its something with the values that are set for the BUG. I see the same code [here](https://github.com/fijiaaron/QCIntegration/blob/master/QCIntegration/Examples/CreateDefect.cs)

Comment: @Jeroen1984 , I think you solved the problem! Thanks!